# implementation of c2dm in android

Tags: android

I am developing android video application.In which i have to implement cloudtodevicecomputing.
Can anyone suggest me how should i pursue,,,,

Thanks in advance
Tushar

Answer (score 1):

you need to register your application with the Google server and receive the respective registration token from the server in order to use c2dm in your application

[this link will help you to follow the procedure to register your application](http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/index.ht)